# Strategy for managing blocks of template markup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a way to manage blocks of HTML in my scripts, as I'm told my way is too unreadable. Typically, I would write something like the following:

```
app.templates = (function () {
    return {
        status: '{0}<br />{1}',
        date: '{0} - {1}',
        details: '<li><i class="sprite"></i>{0} cart</li> \
                  <li><i class="sprite"></i>{1} total</li> \
                  <li><i class="sprite"></i>{2} items</li>'
```

Then I'd do something like: `$('.status').html(utls.format(app.templates.status, status));`

I do have to manage a non-trivial number of these template blocks, can anyone point me in the direction of a better strategy to do this?

Comment: if you have lots of templates, you may want to look at mustache.js or ember.js

Comment: ^above + [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/), [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template) etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the [knockout templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) approach and put them into script tags with type "text/html" (they will be effectively ignored by the browser). Then you could make an associative lookup and get the template markup by `id`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/html" id="foo">
            <div>here is some markup</div>
        </script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                var templates={};
                $('head script[type="text/html"]')
                    .each(function(idx,scr){
                        var id = $(scr).attr("id");
                        var html = $(scr).html();
                        templates[id]=html;
                    });
                alert(templates["foo"]);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        woo-har!
    </body>
</html>
```